# Map Annotation Callout Title

Tags: swift, mapkit

I was using MapKit and have shown five points of location and the pins are coming too. Now, I want to get a callout when I press on the pin annotation.  How can I get that?

Here is the code:

```
class MultipleAnnotationController: UIViewController {

    let sec22 = Capital(title: "Sector 22", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.7339583, longitude: 76.77261969999995), info: "Sector 22 Aroma")

    let sec34 = Capital(title: "Sector 34", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.7195549, longitude: 76.76394989999994), info: "Aakash Institute")

    let mohali = Capital(title: "Mohali Office", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.707318902730268, longitude: 76.70382329676794), info: "Office Location")

    let rmalerkotla = Capital(title: "Malerkotla Home", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 30.5232076, longitude: 75.88825079999992), info: "Home")

    let delhi = Capital(title: "New Delhi", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.7040592, longitude: 77.10249019999992), info: "Capital of India")

    @IBOutlet weak var mapV: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        mapV.addAnnotations([sec22, sec34, mohali, rmalerkotla, delhi])

        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {

        var title: String?

        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

        var info: String

        init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {

            self.title = title

            self.coordinate = coordinate

            self.info = info

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you have a class inside another class? This doesn't look right...

Comment: So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the following method,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "Pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Don't forget to set `mapV.delegate`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapV.addAnnotations([sec22, sec34, mohali, rmalerkotla, delhi])
    mapV.delegate = self
}
```